# On finding the asymptotic distribution of the coefficient of variation

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, asymptotics

Given an IID sample $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with $\mu \ne 0$ let

$$(S_n)^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n ( X_i - \overline{X_n})^2$$

I want to find the distribution of the coefficient of variation $\frac{S_n}{\bar{X}_n}$ where $\bar{X}_n$ is the sample mean. I have come up with an entire solution but there appears to be an error I can't find.

**MY SOLUTION**:

$S_n$ is asymptotically consistent for $\sigma \implies \frac{S_n}{\sigma} \rightarrow^p 1$

Since $\bar{X}_n$ converges to a normal distribution (by the central limit theorem)  from the delta method we have that $\sqrt{n} \frac{\sigma}{\bar{X}_n}$ converges in distribution to $$  \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^2}Z $$

where $Z \sim N(\frac{\sigma}{\mu}, 1) $ this is because having chosen $\phi(x) = \frac{\sigma}{x} \implies \phi'(x) = -\frac{\sigma}{x^2} $.

Now from Slutsky's theorem we have that $$\sqrt{n} \frac{S_n}{\bar{X}_n } = \sqrt{n}\frac{S_n/ \sigma}{\bar{X}_n / \sigma} \rightarrow^d N( \frac{\sigma}{\mu},\frac{\sigma^4}{\mu^4} )$$

Except the solution I am given has $N(\frac{\sigma}{\mu},\frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu^2})$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The independence of mean and SD for the normal distribution is of note here. That aside: a restriction to non-zero mean still commits you to negative coefficient of variation (CV) for negative mean and arbitrarily large CV as the mean approaches zero. The CV has some use and  theoretical interest for data that are positive and positively skewed or distributions like the lognormal or gamma, but it's hard to see point to it for the normal. See its tag for more on uses and limitations..

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for your answer, even though it is not useful I wanted to check my solution to an exercise and I can't find my error.

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer! But you haven't addressed any of my points (e.g. about negative means). How does the question arise? Is from a textbook, or a course, or did you think it up yourself?

Comment: @NickCox Sorry I see your points and I think they are absolutely valid, I guess the exercise (that I took from some friends lecture) has little practical use and is just testing the use of theorems taught up to that point.